# Windows Search don't find any settings, and default softwares

Tags: windows-10, windows-search

After I moved most of folders from ProgramData to my D drive, and did a `mklink`, when I'm searching for something like "paint", "virtual keyboard", and any settings suggestion for when you write for example "mouse"

I tried lot of random things, changing permission of `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data` to me, etc...
But nothing changed.
One of the posts that I managed to find again, where i tried everything :
[Start menu shortcuts and settings not appearing in start menu search](https://superuser.com/questions/1607671/start-menu-shortcuts-and-settings-not-appearing-in-start-menu-search)

Since my problem differ a bit from other posts, i'm asking here
I also removed the mklink for all folders that are not from softwares installed by me, but it's the same

Comment: Hi, please kindly check if this could help you: https://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator

Comment: Yes thanks it worked,
i had a little bug where i couldn't start explorer again, but i just restarted my pc and it work perfectly ! thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Sunny :
Hi, please kindly check if this could help you:
[Windows 10 Search can't find ANY applications. Even calculator](https://superuser.com/questions/947392/windows-10-search-cant-find-any-applications-even-calculator)