# Shortcuts in Start menu

Tags: windows, windows-8, start-menu

I have a Start folder in my user's folder, and there I put shortcuts to software I want to appear in the Start menu if I type the shortcut's name; I have it indexed, but while some icons appears, others don't, and in one case one appeared, then stopped appearing.

I tried rebuilding the index, but it didn't help, and copying and modifying one of the icons that do appear, which sometimes helped, sometimes not.

I tried adding the shortcuts directly to the Start menu folder in AppData, here too mixed results.

I'm unable to understand why despite being indexed some icons appear while searching in the Start menu while others don't, with no apparent difference.

I'm on Windows 10 Pro version 21H2 build 19044.2251.

Comment: Looks like you have to copy it to `"C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs"` and the `appdata` location both, then rebuild the index, then delete the one where you do not want it to reside. Test to confirm you can get it with search, and I'd even reboot and try again.  See this post too https://superuser.com/questions/1607671/start-menu-shortcuts-and-settings-not-appearing-in-start-menu-search

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work: at least sometimes it seems to see the shorcut in the Start Menu folder, but not he one in my folder, and if I delete the one in Start Menu it doesn't see the shortcut anymore. I'll try as said in that link, but I already have another folder and the index doesn't see all the shorcuts in it (but it does see some of them).

Comment: Create a new user on your machine and then start adding items to this location: %ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs.

Comment: If there are no issues at all with the new user then there's something up with your existing user profile. It might be worth migrating what you need to the other new user profile.